# Eclipse (Rational Application Developer) is missing Ant Option in windows > preference

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ant, ibm-rad

I am trying to use the services offered by the Apache Ant plugin in Eclipse (RAD), such as automatically generating build.xml files and running them as Ant builds.
[In this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k3GF.png), the Ant option is nowhere to be found when I go to
Windows > Preferences. [When trying to run a build.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB4Rq.png), I have no option to run it as Ant.

It's like I'm missing the Ant plugin altogether. However, in the plugin directory for RAD, the Ant folder is there, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY7XB.png).

Going to Help > Installation Details > Plug-ins shows [Ant is installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKntd.png)

As well, [Going to Preferences > General > Content Type > Text > XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yehp.png) shows Ant Buildfile as an option.

Comment: Is the plug-in compatible with the version of eclipse?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages about the ant plugins.

Comment: The Ant plugins are pretty old (all of them are more than 6 years behind) and they might not working when running RAD with Java 9 or higher (maybe even not with Java 8). There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).